# Read a file line by line, sometimes reading the next line within same loop

Tags: python

I'd like to read a file in python line by line, but in some cases (based on an if condition) I'd also like to read the next line in the file, and then keep reading it the same way.

Example:

```
    file_handler = open(fname, 'r')
    for line in file_handler:
       if line[0] == '#':
           print line
       else:
           line2 = file_handler.readline()
           print line2
```

basically in this example I am trying to read it line by line, but when the line does not start with `#` I'd like to read the next line, print it, and then keep reading the line after line2.  This is just an example where I got the error for similar stuff I am doing in my code but my goal is as stated in the title.

But I'd get an error like `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`.

Would it be possible to do what I am trying to do in a smarter way?

Comment: In your loop, just skip lines you're not interested in.

Comment: @dave I m interested in all the lines, it's just that sometimes I need to read two lines instead of one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to skip over lines not starting with `#`, there's a much easier way to do this:

```
file_handler = open(fname, 'r')
    for line in file_handler:
       if line[0] != '#':
           continue
       # now do the regular logic
       print line
```

Obviously this kind of simplistic logic won't work in all possible cases. When it doesn't, you have to do exactly what the error implies: either use iteration consistently, or use read methods consistently. This is going to be more tedious and error-prone, but it's not *that* bad.

For example, with `readline`:

```
while True:
    line = file_handler.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if line[0] == '#':
        print line
    else:
        line2 = file_handler.readline()
        print line2
```

Or, with iteration:

```
lines = file_handler
for line in file_handler:
    if line[0] == '#':
        print line
    else:
        print line
        print next(file_handler)
```

However, that last version is sort of "cheating". You're relying on the fact that the iterator in the `for` loop is the same thing as the iterable it was created from. This happens to be true for files, but not for, say, lists. So really, you should do the same kind of `while True` loop here, unless you want to add an explicit `iter` call (or at least a comment explaining why you don't need one).

And a better solution might be to write a generator function that transforms one iterator into another based on your rule, and then print out each value iterated by that generator:

```
def doublifier(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        line = next(it)
        if line.startswith('#'):
            yield line, next(it)
        else:
            yield (line,)
```

Comment: sorry for posting such a trivial example but no, my goal is to read line by line, and then (only sometimes based on a given condition) two lines by two lines

Comment: @Ionut Hulub, u re right, I saw the Q before finished, thanks abamert!

Comment: @Dnaiel: For your simple case, it doesn't really matter whether you print the two lines together, or separately… but yeah, if you're doing some kind of processing besides just `print` it probably will.

Comment: The second example, using `.readline()`, will print a blank line if the input has a line not starting with `#` but then end-of-file.  That's probably not a problem, and you could fix it only printing `line2` when its length is greater than 0.

Comment: @steveha: Good point, but… that seems like it should be invalid data. So I'm not actually sure whether that should print a blank line, not print a blank line, or raise an exception.

Comment: While we're at it… this smells like code to parse some file format that uses # comments. Which implies that he may want to actually read all the `#`-prefixed lines plus the first one without. In which case he wants a `while` rather than `if` (with some slightly more complicated structure)… or maybe `itertools.groupby` (with a slightly complicated keyfunc)…

Comment: Hmm.  It might be best if the code raises an exception if the input is short a line... this sort of thing is why I like using a generator function to stick all the special input handling in one place, and then the loop where you actually process the input is clean and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_handler = open(fname, 'r')
for line in file_handler:
   if line.startswith('#'): # <<< comment 1
       print line
   else:
       line2 = next(file_handler) # <<< comment 2
       print line2
```

#### Discussion

1. Your code used a single equal sign, which is incorrect. It should be double equal sign for comparison. I recommend to use the .startswith() function to enhance code clarity.
2. Use the `next()` function to advance to the next line since you are using `file_handler` as an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

add a flag value:

```
if flag is True:
    print line #or whatever
    flag = False
if line[0] == '#':
    flag = True
```

This is versatile version :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can save a bit of state information that tells you what to do with the next line:

```
want_next = False
for line in open(fname):
    if want_next:
        print line
        want_next = False
    elif line[0] == '#':
        print line
        want_next = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `next` rather than `readline`.
A few things. In your code, you use = rather than ==. I will use startswith instead. If you call next on an iterator, it will return the next item or throw a StopIteration exception.

**The file**

```
ewolf@~ $cat foo.txt
# zork zap
# woo hoo
here is 
some line
# a line
with no haiku
```

**The program**

```
file_handler = open( 'foo.txt', 'r' )
for line in file_handler:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith( '#' ):
        print "Not Skipped : " + line
    elif line is not None:
    try:
        l2 = file_handler.next()
            l2 = l2.strip()
            print "Skipping. Next line is  : " + l2
        except StopIteration:
            # End of File                                                       
            pass
```

**The output**

```
Not Skipped : # zork zap
Not Skipped : # woo hoo
Skipping. Next line is  : some line
Not Skipped : # a line
Skipping. Next line is  :
```

Comment: You can make your code more portable from Python 2.x to Python 3.x by using `next(file_handler)` rather than `file_handler.next()`.  Also, I recommend using a generator function to package up the special input processing; see my solution for an example.

Comment: Good to know! I had started typing before I saw your comprehensive response. I will use the next( iter ) for my own code.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer as @abarnert already covered the same ground.  For an example of using a generator function to package up the special input processing, please see `doublifier()` in his answer.

Answer (score -2):

try `if line[0] == "#"` instead of line[0] = "#"

Comment: He does need to fix that, but that isn't the problem with his code.